# How to connect with separate redis instance in resque rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque, resque-scheduler

There are two in redis setup and their instances in my app. One for redis cache. I want that for background jobs I will use another instance.

I can't find a way where i define resqu to use specific redis address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [in the readme](https://github.com/resque/resque#Configuration), you can point Resque to any Redis using the configuration file.

```
# config/resque.yml:

development: some_host:6379
```

Then using [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) you can configure a different connnection for the cache, for example:

```
# config/environments/development.rb:

config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://other_host:6379/0/cache"
```

You would need to fill it in for the other environments as well.